# ImageView урезает качество картинки загруженной Glide-ом

Tags: java, android, kotlin, test-automation

Есть вот такой UI тест. Суть его в том, чтоб проверить, что загруженная в ImageView картинка соответствует ожидаемой. Для этого я полностью дублирую то как она загружается Glide-ом и сравниваю ее с картинкой в ImageView.

```
@Test
fun verifyImage() {
    val imageView = getView(withId(R.id.myImageView), ImageView::class.java)
    val btmp = (imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap

    val newBtmp = Glide.with(targetContext)
        .asBitmap()
        .load("some image url")
        .transform(FitCenter(), CircleCrop())
        .submit(imageView.width, imageView.height)
        .get()

    assertTrue(newBtmp.sameAs(btmp))
}
```

Когда я получаю картинки то вижу следущее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинки абсолютно одинаковы, но в картинке внутри ImageView есть небольшие потери в качестве и как мне кажется из-за этого при сравнении bitmap-ов я получаю false.

Может мне кто-то объяснить почему так происходит и можно ли как-то это обойти. Может быть как-то руками воспроизвести поведение так, чтоб в ожидаемой картинке тоже было снижено качество

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, как картинка загружена и отображена в приложении? Можете показать код этот?

Comment: Да нечего показывать. Картинки обе взяты из дебаггера. Т.е. код загрузки картинки в тесте идентичен коду загрузки картинки в реальном коде. Когда начинаешь дебажить и опускаешься к тому методу где идет непосредственно сравнение, можно как раз обе картинки визуально и глянуть. И вот глазами видно, что они разные. Сравниваются они там нативным каким-то методом (наверн побайтно или по пикселям, хз)

Comment: Судя по исходникам [ImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java#752), для создания BitmapDrawable используются ресурсы, видимо как раз для оптимизации под разные разрешения. Возможно, вам стоит, исходя из этого, попробовать сравнивать не Bitmap, но BitmapDrawable. Типа как-то так: `(imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable) == BitmapDrawable(imageView.resources, newBtmp)`. Ну и меня реально смущает то, что вы, получается, не прямо в ImageView Glide-ом отображаете картинку, но сначала её в Bitmap загружаете)

Comment: Нет, в коде то я загружаю сразу в ImageView. Разница в том что в коде я использую метод into, а тут просто получаю методом get.

Comment: Наверное в этом и дело. Возможно в ImageView какие-то паддинги явные/неявные есть. Может быть тогда грузить в тесте также в ImageView эту, заранее сохранив то, что в неё уже загружено, чтобы потом сравнить то что было, с тем что загрузилось?

Comment: Ну тут другая проблема. Тест выполняется не на UI потоке, а загружать что-либо во View можно только на UI потоке. А так я тоже пришел к выводу, что сам ImageView каким-то образом сжимает картинку. И хочется понять: "Можно ли это как-то воспроизвести в тесте?"